# How to identify LINQable parts in pre-.NET 3.5 code?

Tags: c#, linq, design-patterns, refactoring, linq-to-objects

This is the scenario: I have a huge code-base written in .NET 2.0...and sometime back the migration happened to .NET 3.5.

This code-base is both refactored and enhanced as an ongoing maintenance project. I am looking for patterns to identify in code base which are good candidates for **LINQ to Objects.**

I need pointers for comprehensive analysis in identifying LINQ-to-Object-phillic areas of my code.

Answer (score 2):

Operations on collections (searching, sorting, filtering, transforming) etc. is the best place to look for places to utilize LINQ. Look for loops that operate imperatively on collections.

Answer (score 2):

[ReSharper 5](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/documentation/whatsnew_50.html#code_analysis) (not released yet) has an "Upgrade to LINQ" feature in its code analysis that's pretty amazing (several coworkers have early access versions installed).

EDIT: Here's a [screen shot](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/screenshots/50/foreach_to_linq.png) of the feature in action from the site.

Answer (score 1):

**Loops** are the first candidates to be replace by Linq2Objects.

Answer (score 0):

Foreach loops, generally with ifs inside, would be a more specific place I'd pick to start with.